# Where I edit the text of the waiting chat window, as shown in the image below?

Tags: pre-chat, bots, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

Where I edit the text of the waiting chat window, as shown in the image below?

The priority is to change the informational text but if you can change the text of the button and the window title it will also be good.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making changes in labels under additional branding which is under embedded service deployment in the setup I was able to alter the values

1. 'waiting to chat' to 'Waiting Test Mess'
2. 'An agent is on the way' to 'Testing Agent Message'
3. 'cancel chat request' to 'guest cancel request'

Click Path: setup > embedded service deployment> scroll to the deployment > click on drop down menu > click view > chat settings> Additional branding > edit > Labels > Chat State > Waiting > Label Group > Queue Position not displayed

After following the above click path you can change the necessary messages here.

Below are the screenshots for the same and the result for reference:

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Anujet!